# I am building an app that show a list of texts when i click my button

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

For now the texts shows immediately i run the instead of waiting for a click before showing, this is the my code of the app I can't pinpoint what is wrong especially the button aspects.

```
val title: List<String> = mutableListOf(
    "My Name is Andrei",
    "My name is Guita",
    "My name is Samuel",
    "Andrei has a decision to make")

val description: List<String> = mutableListOf(
    "I am trying to learn Jetpack Compose",
    "I am an android developer",
    "Jetpack Compose has been fun with headaches",
    "Between Recycler View and LazyColumn which is best")

var position by remember {
    mutableStateOf(Random.nextInt(0,title.size-1))
}
val OnClick = {
    position = Random.nextInt(0, title.size-1)
}

Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.rose),
        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.flower_name),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
    )
    Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.text))
    Text(text = title[position])
    Text(text = description[position])
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 30.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            contentColor = Color.Black,
            backgroundColor = Color.White
        ),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
        onClick = OnClick ) {
        Text(stringResource(id = R.string.btn_text))
    }
```

Comment: Hello! Please don't paste screen shots of code. Paste the text of your code into your question. You can edit it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i have made changes kindly take a look at it

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to show any text at all until after the button is clicked for the first time?

Comment: @Tenfour04  Yes that what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track whether it is time to show the Texts yet. Easiest way here would be to use a negative number for `position` to represent the state when you don't show it, so set your initial value to `-1`:

```
var position by remember {
    mutableStateOf(-1)
}
```

Then, you simply don't include the Text when the position is negative:

```
if (position >= 0) {
    Text(text = title[position])
    Text(text = description[position])
}
```

If you want the text to take up space in the layout even if you're not showing it yet, then you should set the alpha to zero instead of not using them. It's a few more steps since you can't use the `position` if it's negative.

```
val textModifier = Modifier.alpha(if (position >= 0) 1f else 0f)
val textPosition = position.coerceAtLeast(0)
Text(text = title[textPosition], modifier = textModifier)
Text(text = description[textPosition], modifier = textModifier)
```

By the way, getting the random new position can be simplified to:

```
position = title.indices.random()
```